# masking with 3d object in unity

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders

I have a 3d plane in my scene and some 3d objects behind that plane.
So, i want to render only the part behind the 3d plane.[image]

So how should I do this, should I have to use custom shaders, plz help.

Comment: https://youtu.be/7vFwTt4isDY : I think this is what you needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of thing is typically done with the stencil buffer. This has a couple of downsides for your use case in Unity though:

1. It would require modifying the shaders used for all of your through-the-looking-glass objects to check the stencil buffer (which can get annoying if you're using a lot of materials, or relying on shaders you haven't authored yourself, such as from a library or generated by another tool)
2. If you're using deferred rendering, [Unity will ignore your stencil settings for the base and lighting passes anyway](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html) and only use them for the final shading pass, so you won't save as much fill rate as you might expect by stencil testing.

So, I'd lean toward doing it in a slightly less elegant way with multiple cameras and a rendertarget, because it will be quicker to get up & running and flexible as you add new objects & materials to your scene. It also makes it straightforward to apply image effects selectively to the objects on the other side.

1. Create a new layer in your project, I'll call it "Other Side," and place all the objects that you want visible through the plane into this layer. (You can do this with multiple layers too, if you need to maintain layer distinctions between them, like Other Side Obstacles and Other Side FX...)
2. Duplicate your camera (or set up a script that automatically duplicates the camera at runtime and keeps the two copies' parameters in-sync) and make both copies children of one parent. Put any camera movement scripts on the parent so it moves the cloned cameras as one.
3. Set one camera to Depth -1 (so it renders earlier) and its CullingMask to see only the Other Side layer(s). Set the other camera's CullingMask so that it does not see the Other Side layer(s), and ensure its ClearFlags wipe whatever comes before it ("Skybox" is usually what you want).
4. Create a new RenderTexture at the resolution of your game. (If you need to support multiple resolutions, you can write a script that creates/replaces this texture at runtime). Select the camera that sees the Other Side and set its Target Texture to use this RenderTexture.
5. Create a new material for your portal plane, using a shader something like this:

   ```
   Shader "Unlit/ScreenspaceTexture"
   {
   Properties
   {
       _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
   }
   SubShader
   {
       Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Geometry"}
       LOD 100

       Lighting Off

       Pass
       {
           CGPROGRAM
           #pragma vertex vert
           #pragma fragment frag
           // make fog work
           #pragma multi_compile_fog

           #include "UnityCG.cginc"

           struct appdata
           {
               float4 vertex : POSITION;
               float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
           };

           struct v2f
           {
               float3 screenPos : TEXCOORD0;
               UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
               float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
           };

           sampler2D _MainTex;
           float4 _MainTex_ST;

           v2f vert (appdata v)
           {
               v2f o;
               o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
               o.screenPos = o.vertex.xyw;

               // This might be platform-specific. Test with OpenGL.
               o.screenPos.y *= -1.0f;

               UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
               return o;
           }

           fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
           {
               // sample the texture
               float2 uv = (i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.z) * 0.5f + 0.5f;

               fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);

               // apply fog
               UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);               
               return col;
           }
           ENDCG
       }
   }
   }
   ```

(The fog stuff is part of Unity's default unlit shader, but you can delete it if you don't need to use fog in your scene)

Set this material's texture to be the RenderTexture you created in step 4. Now the contents of that RenderTexture will be visible "through" any geometry that has this material applied.

If you need to alpha-test or blend this content with stuff behind the plane in the second camera's view, that will require some modifications.

Note that this method looks correct from the perspective of the in-game cameras, but won't look correct in general in the Scene view, since it doesn't have a duplicate camera of its own. There are ways to fix this if you need, but they get a bit more complex.

Comment: I used nearly the same approach, and it worked. Haven't been able to change some GI parameters inside the portal though, mainly had issues with Terrain GI

Comment: It works \o/ :) thanks for the help DMGregory.

Comment: As an aside, you can also put your Other Side camera and objects somewhere away from the others, even at a different scale, using a script to keep the cameras moving in sync through their respective scene sections. This may make it less confusing to edit, and help ensure that collision/physics or illumination from one set of content doesn't spill over into side effects on the other.

Comment: my plane have upside down sky, so i rotate otherside camera 180 on z axis to fix it, is that happen with you as well?

Comment: @imassassin124 see the comment in the shader "This might be platform-specific"? Comment out the line below it. DirectX and OpenGL don't agree about which direction is up in a texture. ;) Comments aren't great for extended discussion, but I can chat on another forum if you'd like to have more back-and-forth on this.

Comment: I've changed **o.screenPos.y *= -1.0f;** to **o.screenPos.y *= 1.0f;** and it works for me, now there is no upside down sky and the objects also renders correctly. Thanks ^_^